# Multiple while loops?

Tags: php

Trying to figure out a decent way to get a multiple while loops to work properly.

What I have been using is:

```
$x = "0";
$y = "0";

while($x <= "7"){

while($y <= "7"){

echo $x . "-" . $y ."<br />"; 

$y++;
}
$x++;
}
```

Trying to get that to display:

1-1
1-2
1-3
...
1-7
2-1
2-2

etc

Anyone able to provide a quick snippet?

Comment: Typically you'd use for loops for iteration.

Comment: You should most likely be using a `for` loop for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset y after it exits the while loop:

```
$x = "0";
$y = "0";

while($x <= "7"){

    while($y <= "7"){

        echo $x . "-" . $y ."<br />"; 

        $y++;
    }

    $y = "1";
    $x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `$y` to 1 inside the first `while` loop.

```
$x = "0";


while($x <= "7") {
    $y = "1";
    while($y <= "7"){
        echo $x . "-" . $y ."<br />"; 
        $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
```

Better approach is to use `for` loop to do this.

```
for ($x=1; $x<=7; $x++) {
    for ($y=1; $y<=7; $y++) {
        echo $x . "-" . $y ."<br />"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The for actually works 100% better, as I'm adding a third layer to it. 

I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes when it lets me.

Any chance you know how to limit it as well?

For instance, if z = 3, I'd want the y and x limit to be 8.

so it would show 3-8-8, then start at 4-0-0.

Comment: Just modify the condition statement in the for loop. `for ($x=1; $x<=3; $x++)`. To add the third layer, just add another `for` loop inside the second `for` loop. [Demo](http://codepad.org/Pr1Lt5eb)